# Selenium WebDriver throwing error while selecting the xpath

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type="+"checkbox"+"]/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),"+"template"+"]"))
```

My HTML is like this

```
<tr>
<td class="tablecontent">
<input type="checkbox" value="59781" name="templateIds">
</td>`enter code here`
<td class="tablecontent"> test11 </td>
</tr>
```

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector
>   //input[@type=checkbox]/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),template]
>   is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following
>   error occurred: InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with
>   the xpath expression
>   //input[@type=checkbox]/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),template]
>   because of the following error: [Exception... "The expression is not a
>   legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)" 
>   location:
>   "file:///C:/Users/sanjdash/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3529970525380845680webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js
>   Line: 5956"] Command duration or timeout: 72 milliseconds For
>   documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html Build
>   info: version: '2.37.0', revision:
>   'a7c61cbd68657e133ae96672cf995890bad2ee42', time: '2013-10-18
>   09:51:02'

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your messed up with quotes. Use single quotes in XPath to avoid issues like this.

```
// if template is the text within your XPath
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(), 'template']"));

// if template is your variable, then it should be
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(), " + template + "']"));
```

Also, please read the error carefully, it tells enough information you need already. As you can see, there are no quotes in the selector in the message.

> The given selector
>   //input[@type=checkbox]/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),template]
>   is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.

Comment: @user2939258: Looks like you have never accepted any answers before. Just so you know if this answer fixes your issue, please consider accepting it. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220697) Otherwise provide some feedback here.

Answer (score 2):

Your "contains" function has no closing bracket
and needs the right quoting.

If CHECKBOX and TEMPLATE are Strings, try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),'template')]"))
```

if they are variables, try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='" +checkbox+"']/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),'"+template+"')]"))
```

Comment: Remember that you can use the curly-brace button (or surrounding the code with a pair of ` `) in the answer text editor to put lines of code into a container. This makes your answer more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
"//input[@type="+"checkbox"+"]/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),"+"template"+"]"
```

produces a wrong string. Try from python:

```
"//input[@type="+"checkbox"+"]/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),"+"template"+"]"
'//input[@type=checkbox]/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),template]'
```

You should surround checkbox and template with quotes to get

```
"//input[@type="checkbox"]/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),"template"]"
```

or

```
"//input[@type='checkbox']/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),'template']"
```

use

```
"//input[@type="+"'checkbox'"+"]/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),"+"'template'"+"]"
```

or

```
"//input[@type='{type}']/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),'{text}']".format(type='checkbox',text='template')
```