# The given selector Comments button is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

My Selenium server generates following error when trying to access a dom element with Xpath `//*[@id="someid"]/div/div/div/a`.

```
WARN - Exception: The given selector Comments button is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression Comments button because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
```

This XPath works fine with Firefox when used in console but fails when running Automated test with Selenium Hq + Facebook Webdriver, with above exception of course.

What could be wrong since the Xpath seems alright to me.

Comment: Sounds like possibly your Selenium code is misusing quotes or something, so that the literal string `Comments button` is being understood as the XPath expression. Usually that error message shows the actual XPath expression after "The given selector" (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694631/selenium-webdriver-throwing-error-while-selecting-the-xpath). Can you post the code that's sending the XPath expression to Selenium server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like possibly your Selenium code is misusing quotes or something, so that the literal string `Comments button` is being understood as the XPath expression.

Usually that error message shows the actual XPath expression after "The given selector", as in [Selenium WebDriver throwing error while selecting the xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694631/selenium-webdriver-throwing-error-while-selecting-the-xpath).

> The given selector
>   //input[@type=checkbox]/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),template]
>   is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a lot of stuff.

Maybe webdriver starts and finishes looking and the element has not loaded yet, or maybe the element is invisible, or there is another element on top the element that doesnt allow you to interact.

Maybe you are using a different browser for executing the tests (not firefox). In IE the most, the HTML code may be different, and you may have extra or less HTML elements.

Maybe manually you access to the webpage, and the automation redirects to a different webpage (for example, you record the test in google.fr, and the automation goes to google.com).

There are tons of possibilities.

Comment: The element does show up through javascript. I thought at first it might be scree size issue but full-screen does not have any effect either.